Understanding need of orientation in ML based inertial odometry
I was going through following research papers that apply different machine learing approaches to IMU data to predict pose of the target device (mobile or micro aerial vehicle):
[1] GPS-Denied Navigation Using Low-Cost Inertial Sensors and Recurrent Neural
Networks
[2] RIOT: Recursive Inertial Odometry Transformer for Localisation from Low-Cost IMU Measurements
[3] End-to-End Learning Framework for IMU-Based 6-DOF Odometry
[4] AbolDeepIO: A Novel Deep Inertial Odometry Network for Autonomous Vehicles
[5] IONet: Learning to Cure the Curse of Drift in Inertial Odometry
[6] RoNIN: Robust Neural Inertial Navigation in the Wild: Benchmark, Evaluations, and New Methods
I am confused about need for using heading information (from magnetometer) as an input to the model during training.
My understanding is that we need heading information in addition to accelerometer and gyroscope readings as a model input during training for it to learn predicting delta position (displacement) in world frame. For example consider model M takes only accel and gyro reading as input and learns to predict delta position or displacement as (Δn,Δe,Δd) (NED being world frame):

In this case, the model will predict same (Δn,Δe,Δd), whenever it encounters same accel and gyro input even when we have IMU at same position P0, but with different orientation h0’. However, in reality, same accel and gyro input might take it to different position P1’ due to different heading h0’:

This makes me it difficult to understand how some of above papers use of only accel and gyro input for model training.
First two papers use magnetometer as input to the model for training. Second paper explicitly says:

By incorporating magnetometer measurements we enable the system to determine its initial attitude.

Rest of the papers does not use as heading information in any form as an input for model during training.
Third paper says:

The proposed solution for the 6-DOF odometry with an IMU takes a sequence of gyroscope and accelerometer readings as input, and outputs a relative pose between two sequential moments. By successively performing this operation over time, a 3D trajectory can be estimated. Given an initial position and orientation, the computed pose changes are incrementally composed to finally obtain the pose in the reference coordinate system.

Fourth paper says:

Modeling learning procedure in this manner is because IMU measurements are relative to the base node and not the world coordinate, and so it is not possible to design the network to output and learn the exact x, y and z measurements directly.

However both paper uses EuRoC MAV dataset which specifies pose captured by Vicon motion capture system. That means for learning to estimate delta position in the frame of motion capture system, we must need heading information along with accel and gyro data as model input, correct?
Fifth paper derives equation to help get rid of need of orientation (heading) information. It says:

We can compute the absolute change in distance over a window as the L-2 norm i.e. Δl = ||ΔL||2, effectively decoupling the distance traveled from the orientation (e.g. heading angle) traveled, leading to



Even though I can somewhat get the above equation, I am not fully able to build real world / logical intuition about how this gets rid of the requirement of heading information in the model input during training.
Last paper does not seem to discuss the model architecture and input in clear words, but from their source code, it seem that they indeed use only gyro and accelerometer data. The paper however say following (section 4.1):

RoNIN uses a heading-agnostic coordinate frame (HACF), that is, any coordinate frame whose Z axis is aligned with gravity. In other words, we can pick any such coordinate frame as long as we keep it consistent through out the sequence. The coordinate transformation into HACF does not suffer from singularities or discontinuities with proper rotation representation, e.g. with quaternion.
During training, we use a random HACF at each step, which is defined by randomly rotating ground-truth trajectories on the horizontal plane. IMU data is transformed into the same HACF by the device orientation and the same horizontal rotation. The use of device orientations effectively incorporates sensor fusion into our data-driven system. At test time, we use the coordinate frame defined by system device orientations from Android or iOS, whose Z axis is aligned with gravity.

In section 5.2, it says:

For RoNIN, we use the estimated device orientations if the end-sequence alignment error is below 20 degree, otherwise choose the ground-truth to minimize noise during training.

My guess is that the authors of papers 3 and 4 are mistaken to not consider magnetometer input for model training. Third paper does not give any visualization of ground truth and predicted trajectories. Fourth paper indeed give trajectories with some very poor predictions, which I believe are due to change in the IMU orientation as discussed in the diagram. Second paper gives more consistent trajectories given have used magnetometer input. Fifth paper gives okayish trajectories
I will love to know following:

Is magnetometer information / heading information essential for training model to predict delta position?
If answer to above is NO, then how a model can learn to predict delta position merely from gyro and accel data?
What is the intuition behind fifth paper equations for getting rid of heading / orientation information requirement for model training?

